# nginx error - failed (2: No such file or directory) ubuntu

Tags: ubuntu, nginx, laravel-5.5

I have configured laravel project in my Ubuntu server with nginx when I try to access `domain.in/anypage` it gives me error like this for every page that I access,

> *2 open() "/var/www/html/domain/public/admin" failed (2: No such file or directory), client: xx.xx.xx.xx, server: xxx.xx.xxx.xx, request:
>   "GET /admin HTTP/1.1", host: "domain.in"

I have tried all possible solutions but nothing works. Any suggestions,please?

Comment: Looks like access issue for the nginx user being used.

Comment: @TarunLalwani : Thank you and I sorted out the issue :) It was the problem with location URL in server block code .

Comment: @06011991 what specifically was the location URL problem?